# Query data from one column depending on other values on the table

Tags: sql

So, I have a table `table` with three columns I am interested in : `value`, `entity` and `field_entity`.

There are other columns that are not important for this question. There are many different types of `entity`, and some of them can have the same `field_entity`, but those two columns determine what the column `value` refers to (if it is an id number for a person or the address or some other thing)

If I need the name of a person I would do something like this:

```
    select value from table where entity = 'person' and field_entity = 'person_name';
```

My problem is I need to get a lot of different values (names, last names, address, documents, etc.), so the way I am doing it now is using a left join like this:

```
select 
  doc_type.value as doc_type,
  doc.value as doc,
  status.value as status
from 
  table doc
  -- Get doc type
    left join table doc_type
      on doc.entity = doc_type.entity
      and doc.transaction_id = doc_type.transaction_id
      and doc_type.field_entity = 'document_type'
  -- Get Status
    left join table status 
      on doc.entity = status.entity
      and doc.transaction_id = status.transaction_id
      and status.field_entity = 'status'

where doc.entity = 'users' and doc.field_entity = 'document' and doc.transaction_id = 11111;
```

There are 16 values or more, and this can get a bit bulky and difficult to maintain, so I was wondering if some of you can point out a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Select multiple rows and transform in your application's code?

Comment: I can't do that in the app, it's a reporting system that only allows SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are not in position to alter the table structure, but can you add views to the database?  If so, you can create views based on the different types of entities in your table.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW view_person AS
SELECT value AS name
FROM doc
WHERE doc.entity = 'person'
AND doc.field_entity = 'name';
```

Then you can write clearer queries:

```
SELECT view_person.name FROM view_person;
```

Comment: Interesting! I will check if I can do that, but I would need one view for each specific value right?

Comment: You would need a separate view for each entity type, if I understand the structure correctly.